# Shopware 6 - Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Amqp\Transport\Connection::ack(): Return value must be of type bool, null returned

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, shopware6

I am struggling to understand why this is not working.
Standard messages queue works just perfect. All custom queues are not.
I can proccess 1 item at the time and then the process dies with this error message:

```
CRITICAL  [console] Error thrown while running command "messenger:consume jma_index --time-limit=55 --memory-limit=1G". Message: "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Amqp\Transport\Connection::ack(): Return value must be of type bool, null returned" ["exception" => TypeError { …},"command" => "messenger:consume jma_index --time-limit=55 --memory-limit=1G","message" => "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Amqp\Transport\Connection::ack(): Return value must be of type bool, null returned"]
TypeError {#1089
  #message: "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Amqp\Transport\Connection::ack(): Return value must be of type bool, null returned"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/amqp-messenger/Transport/Connection.php"
  #line: 432
  trace: {
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/amqp-messenger/Transport/Connection.php:432 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/amqp-messenger/Transport/AmqpReceiver.php:96 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/amqp-messenger/Transport/AmqpTransport.php:59 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/messenger/Worker.php:216 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/messenger/Worker.php:170 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/messenger/Worker.php:107 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/messenger/Command/ConsumeMessagesCommand.php:225 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:298 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1046 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:96 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:299 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:82 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171 { …}
    /var/www/vhosts/nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/shop.nice-wozniak.52-58-185-213.plesk.page/bin/console:77 {
      › $application->setVersion($kernel->getKernel()->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.shopware_version'));
      › $application->run($input);
      › 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Running Shopware 6.4.14.0 on Rabbitmq 3.11.24